# Create additional 'fields' in GDB domain system table (GDB_items)?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.3, oracle-dbms, xml, domains

Is it possible to create additional 'fields' in the geodatabase domain system table (GDB_items) in SDE 10.3/Oracle?

It would be handy to store additional information in domains.
For example:

- CODE [domain coded value]
- NAME [domain description]
- Additional fields: DETAILS, COMMENTS, RELATED_DOCUMENT, etc.

I know it wouldn't be accessible in ArcGIS desktop's out-of-box functionality, but maybe it would be possible to query it with SQL?

The SQL used to access the domain would look like this, but include additional 'fields':

```
select         
    extractvalue(codedvalues.column_value, 'CodedValue/Code') as domain_code, 
    extractvalue(codedvalues.column_value, 'CodedValue/Name') as domain_description
from         
    sde.gdb_items_vw
cross join
    xmlsequence(xmltype(definition).extract('/GPCodedValueDomain2/CodedValues/CodedValue')) codedvalues 
where       
    sde.gdb_items_vw.name = 'STRATEGY'
```

Or, as an alternative, would it be an acceptable practice to create a separate table that is related to the domain by the CODE value? And then join to it using the query mentioned above?

Comment: If you don't mind using a completely unsupported geodatabase,  with the possibilty of corruption at the next upgrade... All-in-all, I'd recommend a parallel table (owned by a different user).

Comment: @Vince: Why owned by a different user?

Comment: To prevent namespace pollution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vince's comment as the answer:

> ...I'd recommend a parallel table.